# Magento multisite - display of product in main site and subsite but order it only through the subsite

Tags: php, magento

we have a subdomain multisite setup. We would like to have products listed in the both the main site (containing many brands/manufacturers) and a separate subsite that caters to that brand specifically.

A visitor to the main site can perform a product search or browse the categories to locate any products. If they click on a product to view it’s information/order, they will be directed to the subsite to have the product display there

Ordering the item will then take them through the cart process of the subsite with unique shipping extensions etc to that site.

Is this possible? Surely if the products are listed in the root site category but display in both, we should be able to tweak the scripta so that is directs to the subsite to order...

We’re not expecting this to be possible without customization, but not sure how to go about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to redirect to the brand site exactly when the product page on the main site is accessed. So what you can do is write an observer for the event `controller_action_postdispatch_catalog_product_view`, check if the current website is the main website and if the product is available on another website. If yes, redirect to this website. I choose postdispatch over predispatch because at this point the product is already loaded and we can easily retrieve the website information.

To do so, create a new module (I spare the basics here), configure the observer:

### config.xml

```
<frontend>
    <events>
        <controller_action_postdispatch_catalog_product_view>
            <observers>
                <your_module>
                    <class>your_module/observer</class>
                    <method>redirectToBrandSite</method>
                </your_module>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_postdispatch_catalog_product_view>
    </events>
</frontend>
```

and implement the logic from above:

### Observer.php

```php
class Your_Module_Model_Observer
{
    const MAIN_WEBSITE_ID = 1;

    public function redirectToBrandSite(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        if (Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getCode() != self::MAIN_WEBSITE_ID) {
            return;
        }
        $product = Mage::registry('current_product');
        if (!$product instanceof Mage_Catalog_Model_Product) {
            return;
        }
        foreach ($product->getWebsiteIds() as $websiteId) {
            if ($websiteId != self::MAIN_WEBSITE_ID) {
                $redirectUrl = $product->setStoreId(
                    Mage::app()->getWebsite($websiteId)->getDefaultStore()->getId()
                )->getProductUrl();
                $observer->getControllerAction()->getResponse()->setRedirect($redirectUrl);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

You have to set the MAIN_WEBSITE_ID constant to the id of your main website (not the code). You can look that up in the `core_website` database.

Answer (score 0):

You can create multiple store to achieve main website and sub site. My be you need to create URL redirections to redirect products to subsite.